# ajax validating input makes input unwritable or hardly writable

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Problem** 
I'm using ajax to validate input when user stops writing, 
basically this works fine, 
but when user wants to write when ajax is not finished, it wont let him or its really slow to write in that input.

Here is some fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qgnjoLch/

```
var myInterval;
var typingTimer;               //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 700;  //time in ms
var doneTypingThis = false;

$('#something').keyup(function(){
    typingTimer = setTimeout(function () {doneTyping('something');}, doneTypingInterval);
    if(!doneTypingThis){
      //some functionality  
    }else {
      doneTyping('something'); 
    }
});

//reset timer
$('#something').keydown(function(){
   clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

// User finished do something
function doneTyping (input_id) {

                        var txt = '';
                        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                          if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                            txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
                          }
                        };
                        xmlhttp.open("GET","catalog/view/javascript/mails.js",true);
                        xmlhttp.send();
                        console.log($.parseJSON(txt));

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://something.com/index.php?route=doesnot/really/matter',
                            type: 'post',
                            async: false,
                            data: 'email=' + $("#"+input_id).val(),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(json) {
                                if(json == "1") {
                                    ajaxValid = false;
                                }else if(json == "2"){
                                    ajaxValid = false;
                                } else if(json == "0") {
                                    ajaxValid = true;

                                }                               
                            }
                        });
                        return ajaxValid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becouse of this line `async: false,` It changes request to be synchronous, and browser will be `frozen` till response will come. To fix it, just remove this line. Then you need to return result from AJAX success function (not after it) but then your code will need to be deeply modified because if request will be asynchronous then your function will return before response will come.

Comment: This line has a crucial reason, form won't be send, before the ajax returns something...

Comment: I know that and I wrote the explanation. If you will decide to use sync requests than it will keep your browser frozen till response come and it will cause performance issue.

Comment: there is one more way to make it async by keep whole validation function inside of setTimeout()

Comment: I cant do that, what I have is far more complicated functionality, i post here just a simplified script, but at least I know, where lies the problem. Thx.